# Visual Studio Code API Key bar keeps dropping down

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to Visual Studio Code. I have used it lightly in the past but need to use more heavily now that I am working with Python. However, the API Key bar keeps coming down when I am typing, trying to create a new file, etc. Does anyone know how to stop it from dropping when ever it feels like it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this happens, there is an extension called WakaTime. Uninstall this extension and everything goes back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Try and restart the platform and then re open the file I had that error a bit ago when working with GoLang but opened a python project up and that seemed to fix it

Comment: I have closed the system, cleared my cache, restarted my laptop. It just keeps coming back. I might just need to uninstall and reinstall the program.